# finding no of rows with missing data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have a data frame

```
Id  Name                      Affiliation
9   Ernest Jordan   
14  K. MORIBE   
15  D. Jakominich   
25  William H. Nailon   
37  P. B. Littlewood      Cavendish Laboratory|Cambridge University
44  A. Kuroiwa            Department of Molecular Biology|School of Science|Nagoya 
75  M. Till-berg
```

I want to find out how many rows are there which are not complete ,ie having missing data.Like in this case rows with ID (9,14,15,25,75) have affiliations missing.So in this case the result should be 5.

I have tried

```
dim(author_data[complete.cases(author_data),])
```

But its not showing the correct result.Its giving output as

```
7  3
```

ie 7 rows and 3 columns

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the data frame author_data, the code below will give you the number of rows with missing data.

```
sum(!complete.cases(author_data))
```

To view which rows have missing data

```
author_data[!complete.cases(author_data), ]
```